# Android 4.3 external and internal sdcard

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, mount

I am new  in `Android` so please be gentle.
I have the problem, that my phone doesn't use the external sdcard and try to save everything on internal 2gb storage.

So I rooted the device and get a shell on my device.
then I checked the mount point and saw that the /dev/fuse is used everywhere

```
   /dev/fuse /mnt/shell/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
   /dev/fuse /storage/emulated/legacy fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
   /dev/fuse /storage/emulated/0 fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
   /dev/fuse /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0

   /dev/block/vold/179:33 /storage/sdcard1 vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

my idea is to change the mounts everywhere and change /dev/fuse to /dev/block/vold/179:33

is there any special program technically location in Android to edit and save the new mount points?
Thanks!!

Comment: don't do that.. there is the option to format your SD to "adoptable storage" which makes it kind of part of the internal storage

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the advice, but in my android 4.3 there is no option like this. I suppose it's only in new android versions. Do you know where can i find fstab or something like this? because vold.fstab is not the right one

Comment: Yes that feature came with 6.0... 4.3 is kind of old. Anyways, I don't know for sure, but in settings -> apps -> <select any app> -> storage , there should be a button ”change” on some of the apps ? I'm not sure if 4.3 had this...

Comment: Sorry I can't give you firsthand experience with this. Best to change your title/question and tags to reflect android 4.3 usage

Comment: there is only mount/unmount, delete and move data to sdcard, but it doesn't use after move, just store.... :D
so there is two ways new os or change the mounts. but I do not know androit enough to find the "fstab" or similar file

Answer (score 0):

Try the SDFix application (for KitKat Writable MicroSD) on Google Play, which simply adds a line to the platform.xml permissions file (at /system/etc/permissions) to allow writing on the extSDCard.